# Reverse for '' with arguments '(u'2016', u'05')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, zinnia

I want to use **zinnia** blog in my django app,for that i customized zinnia blog by using `django-blog-quintet`.
Now when i try to open url it throw an error

```
Reverse for '' with arguments '(u'2016', u'05')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

in template `archives_entries_link.html`

```
1   {% load i18n %}
2   
      {% for date in archives %}<link rel="archives" title="{% trans "Archives" %} {{ date|date:"F Y"|capfirst }}" href="
      {% url zinnia_entry_archive_month date|date:"Y" date|date:"m" %}
      " />


3   {% endfor %}
```

What is this error and why this is happening.

Comment: It means it can't figure out where your URL points because there are no patterns to match. Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the URL name in quotes.

```
{% url "zinnia_entry_archive_month" date|date:"Y" date|date:"m" %}
```